# How to commit one file at a time using Git?

Tags: git

Say there are several files modified and I just want one files committed each time. How to do that? Given an example with status looks like below. Thanks!!

Ex:

```
> git status
#   modified: file01.txt
#   modified: file02.txt
#   modified: file03.txt
#   modified: file04.txt
#   modified: file05.txt
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a few ways, but the simplest is probably:

```
git commit file01.txt
git commit file02.txt
...
```

Any paths you list after the commit command will be committed regardless of whether they're staged to be committed. Alternatively, you can stage each one, and then commit:

```
git add file01.txt
git commit

git add file02.txt
git commit

...
```

Comment: This is regular git commit, but for partial file commit -p or -e is needed

Comment: damn, I should have been reading this comment before using this command. this is the WRONG answer to this question!

Comment: @donschoe The question asks how to commit single files (not parts of files). The answer is correct, even if you would have worded the question title differently (should probably be "how to commit single files).

Comment: @qdoe This is not a problem, you can reset file back (`git reset file01.txt`) and try again (`git add -p file01.txt`).

Comment: @AlexReisner, I too found this confusing so have edited the question title to make it clearer what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 47):

Use `git add -p` followed by `git commit`. `git add -p` asks you for each change whether to stage it for committing, which is super convenient.

You can also use `-p` with `git reset` and `git checkout`.

Comment: I really think that git add -p needs more exposure! It creates much nicer workflow because you don't have to care about filenames, just your changes scrolling by.

Answer (score 14):

`git add -p` described by daf's answer is nice, but for a more direct approach to picking and choosing, I'm really liking:

`git add -e`

It generates the appropriate patch, then loads it up in your preferred editor so that you can edit it as desired. When you save the file and exit the editor, and only the changes made by your edited version of the patch are added to the index.

If you accidentally close the editor without making changes, you'll probably want to use `get reset HEAD` and then start over.

Comment: I now prefer `-e` over `-p` as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
git add file01.txt
git stash
git commit -m'commit message'
git stash pop
```

repeat.

Comment: I was going to down-vote this since there's no reason (from git's perspective) to do the stash.  However, it's not a bad idea if you want to build and test between the stash and commit.  That way you'll know that you're not committing broken code accidentally.

Comment: What's wrong with committing broken code? As long as it's not published and nobody else manages to get hold of it.

Comment: @Pat, I tend to do it out of habit of liking to have working commits and working with git svn where I have to stash changes before uploading changes with dcommit. But you're right, there is no reason in the OPs case to do the stash'n pop

Comment: As the second step you should do `get stash --keep-index`: otherwise staged changes get stashed too.

Comment: I second the suggestion from @AlexanderPoluektov. Without --keep-index these commands won't actually commit anything! (I suggested this as an edit, but it got rejected for reasons I don't understand.)

Answer (score 1):

On the subject of staging partial changes within a file, it's worth noting that various text editors have support for doing this in a nicer way than any of the command-line options.

I use [Magit](https://github.com/magit/magit#readme) for Emacs, which uses single keystrokes for stepping forward or backwards through the hunks, increasing or decreasing the granularity, and staging or un-staging the current hunk. You can also mark a region manually and stage (or un-stage) just that region.

I believe there are similar plugins for vim, and other editors / IDEs as well.