# Commiting GIT part by part

Tags: git

I have made few changes on my working copy of a repository. I haven't committed for a long, and all changes are being tracked.

Now, I want to commit a part of changes first, and then commit another part of the changes later so that I could revert back to each of them. Obviously, these part of the changes are on different files. I am new to git, and so worried that I might undo all the changes if i try few things like git rm --cache which was suggested elsewhere. Kindly help.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003491/11343

Answer (score 3):

You can git gui and 'stage hunk for commit' or 'stage line for commit'

Comment: You can also use `git add -i` as an alternate to using git GUI - less user friendly but works if you only have terminal.

Answer (score 3):

On command line you can use

```
$ git add -p
```

to select the hunks for a commit.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the `-p` option to `git add`. This tells git to
interactively ask the user whether to commit a hunk.

```
$ git add -p src_file.c
$ git commit
$ git add -p src_file.c
$ git commit
...
```

With this option you will get a prompt like this for every hunk:

```
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,s,e,?]?
```

Pressing <kbd>?</kbd> gets you the following help message.

```
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit; do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining ones
a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk nor any of the later hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

Adding like this you can easily split changes to the same file or
multiple files into multiple commits. For a more detailed description
look in [`man (1) git-add`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-add).

Comment: Thanks ... I got the idea, actually I also had a misconception that all modified files are automatically added for next commit. That was wrong until we use commit -a

Answer (score 1):

You can add files to the commit using `git add` command. For example type `git add file.c`, then `file.c` will be commited with the next `git commit`. Any files not added will not be committed. After committing just add the other files and commit again.

You can see which files are staged for a commit by typing `git status`. To add all files, type `git add .`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I don't understand the question, but simply add some files and do a commit, and repeat the process.

```
git add file1 file2
git commit -m "Comment first commit comment"
git add file3 ...
```

Comment: This will solve the OP if and only if they always want to commit whole files - they might want to commit only some parts of files in some occasions.

Comment: Very true, the answer in that case would be to check out hunks and use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to commit all the changes in a subset of the modified files, use `git add <file1> ...`. If you want to be selective about which changes *inside* the files get added to the index, either use `git add -i [<file1> ...]` or the IMHO much more usefule `git add -p [<file1> ...]` which allows you to even modify the diffs that get applied to the index *without* changing the state in your working copy.

Finally, if you are a [Vim](http://vim.org) user, you absolutely must know and use [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive).