# How to add and commit only one file to a remote repository when you have multiple file changes in git

Tags: git

I know my question has been asked before but some of the comments from other questions confuses me so I want to make sure that what I'm thinking is correct before I use any git commands.

Say I have 3 files (with changes), `file1.java`, `file2.txt` and `file3.java`. I only want to commit the changes I've made to `file1.java` to a remote repo but I don't want to remove the changes of the other 2 files from my local machine just yet. How do I commit just `file1.java`?

Based on what I've been reading, [How to commit one file at a time using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003491/how-to-commit-one-file-at-a-time-using-git/2009190), the commands below will work

```
#1
git add file1.java
git commit -m "Comments"
```

but then I see someone commenting

```
This is regular git commit, but for partial file commit -p or -e is needed
```

and another alternative solution I saw was,

```
#2
git add file01.txt
git stash
git commit -m'commit message'
git stash pop
```

What is the right command? Are they all correct? I have a suspicion that by doing `git commit` even though I've only added one file, it will still commit all the changes (ie all 3 files)?

Comment: #1 is fine.  `git add file` (the same as `git stage file`) adds the current state of the file to the index.  `git commit` commits the state of the index.  Since you didn't `git add file2.java`, any changes in that file are not in the index and will not be committed by `git commit`.  There's no need to stash/pop around the commit.  That is someone not understanding git.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22commit+one+file%22

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be confused like me, below did it for me. But other solutions might work too.

```
git add file1.java
git commit -m "Comments"
```